# What is the code behind a number in the Julia REPL?

Tags: julia

I asked myself the simple question in the title.

Here are the results:

```
julia> # Fresh 1.0.0 REPL
julia> VERSION
v"1.0.0"

julia> 2
2
julia> code_lowered(ans)
0-element Array{Union{Nothing, CodeInfo},1}
```

How can `ans` be a `0-element` array to represent a 2?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `2` or any other value of `ans`. Try `x = rand(2,2)` and then `code_lowered(ans)`. It's more how `ans` is lowered I assume.

Comment: I got the same answer as with 2: `0-element Array{Union{Nothing, CodeInfo},1}`  Hmmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`code_lowered` expects a callable as a first argument. Clearly `2` is not callable so it returns array of zero IR, because there exist none for non-callable. Try `code_lowered(Int)` or `code_lowered(sin)` to see that all works fine (first is a type and second is a function - two basic kinds of callables).

It has nothing to do with `ans`. It just checks what `ans` contains, e.g.:

```
julia> f() = 10
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_lowered(ans)
1-element Array{Core.CodeInfo,1}:
 CodeInfo(
1 1 ─     return 10                                                         │
)

julia>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Any more thoughts on what is and what is not a callable?

Comment: Functors (https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1) are callable, but I would not call them that basic :).